# BindableProperty not updated on ViewModel

Tags: xaml, data-binding, xamarin.forms

In Xamarin.Forms I implemented a custom `Picker`.
The `ItemsSource` is set correctly. However when i change the selected item it does not update the property on my ViewModel.

The `BindablePicker`:

```cs
public class BindablePicker : Picker
{
    public BindablePicker()
    {
        this.SelectedIndexChanged += OnSelectedIndexChanged;
    }

    public static BindableProperty ItemsSourceProperty =
        BindableProperty.Create<BindablePicker, IEnumerable>(o => o.ItemsSource, default(IEnumerable), propertyChanged: OnItemsSourceChanged);

    public static BindableProperty SelectedItemProperty =
        BindableProperty.Create<BindablePicker, object>(o => o.SelectedItem, default(object), propertyChanged: OnSelectedItemChanged);


    public IEnumerable ItemsSource
    {
        get { return (IEnumerable)GetValue(ItemsSourceProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ItemsSourceProperty, value); }
    }

    public object SelectedItem
    {
        get { return (object)GetValue(SelectedItemProperty); }
        set { SetValue(SelectedItemProperty, value); }
    }

    private static void OnItemsSourceChanged(BindableObject bindable, IEnumerable oldvalue, IEnumerable newvalue)
    {
        var picker = bindable as BindablePicker;
        picker.Items.Clear();
        if (newvalue != null)
        {
            //now it works like "subscribe once" but you can improve
            foreach (var item in newvalue)
            {
                picker.Items.Add(item.ToString());
            }
        }
    }

    private void OnSelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs eventArgs)
    {
        if (SelectedIndex < 0 || SelectedIndex > Items.Count - 1)
        {
            SelectedItem = null;
        }
        else
        {
            SelectedItem = Items[SelectedIndex];
        }
    }
    private static void OnSelectedItemChanged(BindableObject bindable, object oldvalue, object newvalue)
    {
        var picker = bindable as BindablePicker;
        if (newvalue != null)
        {
            picker.SelectedIndex = picker.Items.IndexOf(newvalue.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

The `Xaml`page:

```xml
<controls:BindablePicker Title="Category"
        ItemsSource="{Binding Categories}"
        SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedCategory}"
        Grid.Row="2"/>
```

The `ViewModel` properties, didn't implement the `NotifyPropertyChanged` on the properties since they only need to be updated from the ´View`to the`ViewModel`:

```cs
public Category SelectedCategory { get; set; }
public ObservableCollection<Category> Categories { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Beside adding the `Mode=TwoWay` to my binding a had to change some things in my picker so it could work with the actual objects i had it bound to.

The `Items` property of the `Xamarin Picker` is an `IList<string>`
since all my items are added to it as a string it keeps the same indexed value.

Therefor the ItemsSource is changed to an `IList`:

```
public IList ItemsSource
    {
        get { return (IList)GetValue(ItemsSourceProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ItemsSourceProperty, value); }
    }
```

I also modified the `SelectedIndexChanged`method so it doesn't retrieve the item from the `Items` but from the `ItemsSource`, wich is in my case an `IList<Category>`:

```
private void OnSelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs eventArgs)
    {
        if (SelectedIndex < 0 || SelectedIndex > Items.Count - 1)
        {
            SelectedItem = null;
        }
        else
        {
            SelectedItem = ItemsSource[SelectedIndex];
        }
    }
```

In my `ViewModel` i no longer use the `ObservableCollection` for my `Categories` but add these items to an `IList<Category>`.

The `ObservableCollection`has no use since when my `BindablePicker` binds to the `ItemsSource` the items are added to the internal `IList<string>`. when adding an item to the collection it will not be updated. I now update the entire `ItemSource`if an item is changed.

Answer (score 5):

When creating your BindableProperty:

```cs
public static BindableProperty SelectedItemProperty =
    BindableProperty.Create<BindablePicker, object>(o => o.SelectedItem, default(object), propertyChanged: OnSelectedItemChanged);
```

without specifying the `defaultBindingMode`, the `BindingMode` is set to `OneWay`, meaning the Binding is updated from source (your view model) to target (your view).

This can be fixed by changing the defaultBindingMode:

```cs
public static BindableProperty SelectedItemProperty =
    BindableProperty.Create<BindablePicker, object>(o => o.SelectedItem, default(object), BindingMode.TwoWay, propertyChanged: OnSelectedItemChanged);
```

or, if it's the default you want for your picker, but want to update the source only in this view, you can specify the BindingMode for this instance of the Binding only:

```xml
<controls:BindablePicker Title="Category"
    ItemsSource="{Binding Categories}"
    SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedCategory, Mode=TwoWay}"
    Grid.Row="2"/>
```

Comment: I tried this allready, didn't help alltough it really should be enabled so a upvote. I did notice when i change my binding property from type Category to object it did succeed, it is just the string value that is pushed back so i will work on that later and update an answer.